# Can't create a 3D Plane in XZ Plane

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I use Aframe library, when creating a plane, I have used these points

`point_1 = [0, 0, 0]`;
`point_2 = [1, 0, 0];`
`point_3 = [1, 1, 0];`
`point_4 = [0, 1, 0];`

to make a plane in  XY plane, It works, code: https://jsfiddle.net/qtv10291/yp4mx6re/8/
But when I change point to:
`point_1 = [0, 0, 0];`
`point_2 = [1, 0, 0];`
`point_3 = [1, 0, 1];`
`point_4 = [0, 0, 1];`

to create a plane in XZ plane, It doesn't work and error **THREE.DirectGeometry: Faceless geometries are not supported.**, code: https://jsfiddle.net/qtv10291/49gvwL8a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Shape`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/core/Shape) is only 2D and only accept `(x, y)` points, The third axis of the points you passed in are ignored.

If you want to create an XZ plane, either [rotate the XY plane 90 degrees](https://jsfiddle.net/1r639nLt/):

```js
const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( polygon );
geometry.rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5);
```

Or create it [via vertices and faces](https://jsfiddle.net/aqd9f6m2/):

```js
const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices = points;
geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 2, 1, 0 ), new THREE.Face3( 2, 0, 3 ) );
```